# How to use DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember of ComboBox in a usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, user-controls, custom-controls

I have a `UserControl` with a `Label` and `ComboBox` on it.
what I'm trying to do is to set it's `DataSource`, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties from the `UserControls` property grid at design time.

To this inside the `UserControl` I set the following properties:

```
public object MyDataSource
{
    get { return myLbComboBox1.DataSource; }
    set { myLbComboBox1.DataSource = value; }
}

public string MyValueMember
{
    get { return myLbComboBox1.ValueMember; }
    set { myLbComboBox1.ValueMember = value; }
}

public string MyDisplayMember
{
    get { return myLbComboBox1.DisplayMember; }
    set { myLbComboBox1.DisplayMember = value; }
}
```

As a result, I can see these properties on the property grid but as can be seen on the image below, they are like `textfields` and `DataSource` is not settable.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this can easily get painful when you use UserControl.  You have to give these properties the same [attributes] that their corresponding ComboBox properties have so they behave the same way at design-time.  It inherits them from ListControl, [have a look-see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,5651aee9c3fdc326).  [Editor], [RefreshProperties], [TypeConverter] are important, copy/paste them.  If the UserControl *only* contains a ComboBox then don't do this, make ComboBox the base class.

Comment: Consider alternatives like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492076/17034) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471982/17034).

Comment: Thank you! you really saved my day! one question though when I copy paste the attributes I get missing reference for SR.. why is that?

Comment: Only copy the ones you need.  SR is used to localize VS controls.